# Is there any way to get the generic type of a collection in the method support() from AbstractHttpMessageConverter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection

I'm trying to create a CSV message converter to use with the `Spring` message converters but I'm not able to configure the `support(Class<?> clazz)` method when `clazz` is of type `Collection`. Basically my `REST` endpoint is returning a `Collection` of objects directly and not wrapped inside another object.

Using reflection, the only thing I'm able to get as the type of the `Collection` is `E` which obviously doesn't give me much to work with.

I've tried manually and also with helper tools like `TypeUtils.genericArrayType(clazz)` from `Apache Commons`.
The only work around I can think of is to just always return true and verify the type inside the `writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage message)` method.

Is this a bug in the implementation of the `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` class that retrieves the return type of the endpoint or am I missing something?

By the way, this is the method that returns the type in the Spring implementation?

```
protected Class<?> getReturnValueType(Object value, MethodParameter returnType) {
    return (value != null ? value.getClass() : returnType.getParameterType());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found the answer. And it's basically `Java's` `type erasure` that deletes the `Collection` type information at runtime. There is another abstract class `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter` which lets me implement `public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType)` and `protected void writeInternal(Object o, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)` methods which contain a `Type` argument that can be used to determine the exact `Class` of the object.